# Docker-compose rsync backup

Tags: docker-compose, graylog

I recently started working with docker-compose, and I'm currently in a situation where I need to upgrade the VM server. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the snapshot/restore option for certain reasons. However, I do have enough free disk space to perform a manual backup inside the server. After delving deeper into various options like rsync, Alpine, docker-compose-backup, Restic, etc., I circled back to rsync as I only need a temporary solution for the upgrade period.

Could you please validate if the approach outlined below is valid? It's a Greylog instance, and the volumes mongo:elasticsearch:graylog are located in ./data.

```
rsync -aAXv /opt/docker/docker-compose.yaml /backups/docker-compose
rsync -aAXv ./data/ /backups/docker-compose/data
```

Comment: There is also a docker container pre build solution for making backups using docker https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-duplicati/. Docker-compose is for creating a container, and I don't see the docker compose configuration where you specify how the container should look like. The only thing your doing is rsync a docker compose directory, I don't see the relationship with upgrading a VM server

Comment: I'm just looking for easy full rollback to original state. If the upgrade fails, as upgrading mongo, graylog and especially elasticsearch is usually not without unexpected problems and errors. Sometimes starting all over again and reassessing the situation is good idea. Bit of a safe net without requesting of full snapshot rollback.

Comment: if its a rent server ask the provider for doing such a thing, offer them to pay it extra. I think that would be a option for the most of them

Comment: The idea is to be a bit self sufficient before going to admin :) and the server is used by others, so rollback might mess up their staff es well (non production tho, so not forbidden, just undesirable). I just wonder if such a rsync of whole thing can work as bit brute backup.

Comment: You can't restore databases like mongo using a file backup or image backup,that will cause major problems. You need to make a database / application aware backup and restore. For mongo you need https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#bin.mongodump

Comment: For elk you need to use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Comment: @Turdie Thank you. Are those major problems caused by doing an rscync on live DB (mongo/elastic)? Because I'm aware of it and can stop the containers first to have solid state during the "backup" to avoid this.

Comment: Rsync does a copy of files and folders and with a database like mongod, that's a fraction of the data, because a database gets constantly updated. So you first need to dump the database with mongodump and then you can rsync it https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tomanagle/56c398efccf1629ee57941c349309c43/raw/d74210431b710750d5393c94e2329627a61bd2be/backup.sh

Comment: @Turdie OK thank you, rsync is probably too brute, i will just dump mongodb, backup compose file and figure out elasticsearch as thats the big one.

Answer (score 0):

check here for backup of graylog
https://go2docs.graylog.org/5-1/setting_up_graylog/backup_considerations.html